# Deployed Outlook add-in doesn't show up in old Outlook (365)

Tags: outlook, generator, add-in, yeoman

I've created en Outlook add-in using the Yeoman Generator for Office add-ins tool ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/yeoman-generator-overview)

I can succesfully release the app trough https://admin.microsoft.com/ > Integrated Apps where I add the manifest.xml and makes it available for the entire organisation.

After that the add-in becomes available on both Outlook online (https://outlook.office.com/mail/) and on the (new) Outlook client - where everything works as intended.

On the old Outlook client (Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20028) 64-bit) however that add-in doesn't show up.

Any idea on how that can be?

*Bonus info.*
When developing the app when I was debugging in VS Code and ran "npm start" it fires up the (old) Outlook client where the add-in actually also runs fine. So it seems that the app can run in the old Outlook but maybe et needs to be deployed some other way.

BR Søren

I was expecting the add-in to show up en the old Outlook client. It seems that there is a lot going on at Microsoft recently when it comes to deploying new outlook/teams etc. and when Googling for answers I run into a lot of articles with screenshots showing UI that have been modified over the past 6-12 months so descriptions on how to add add-ins explain flows that have since been changed and are no longer valid.

Comment: where add-in are not showing up on desktops?